# JavaScript object literal length === undefined?

Tags: javascript, object, properties, object-literal

I am working on this [animation function](http://jsfiddle.net/Wolfy87/dZjnX/20/) but I have a problem. I can't seem to perform what should be an easy task, I can not get the length of an object. If you check out that jsFiddle you can see that I am running `alert(properties.length);` and it is returning `undefined`. Can anyone see why this might be?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Length of Javascript Associative Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223/length-of-javascript-associative-array)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

JavaScript object simply do **not** have a `length` property, only `Arrays` do. If you want to know the number of properties that are defined on a object, you have to iterate over them and count them.

Also, your `for in` loop is prone to bugs due extension of `Object.prototype` since in will traverse the complete **prototype chain** and enumerate **all** the properties that are on the chain.

**Example**

```
// Poisoning Object.prototype
Object.prototype.bar = 1;

var foo = {moo: 2};
for(var i in foo) {
    console.log(i); // logs both 'moo' AND 'bar'
}
```

You have to use the [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) method on the object in order to filter out those unwanted properties.

```
// still the foo from above
for(var i in foo) {
    if (foo.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        console.log(i); // only logs 'moo'
    }
}
```

Many JavaScript frameworks out there extend the prototype, not using `hasOwnProperty` often leads to horrible bugs.

**Update**

Concerning the actual problem that your code is not animation both properties.

```
for(var p in properties) {
    ...
    for(var i = 0; i <= frames; i++)
    {
        setTimeout((function(exti, element) {
            return function() {

                // p gets overriden by for outer for in loop
                element.style[p] = original + (pixels * exti) + 'px';
            }

        // you need to pass in a copy of the value of p here
        // just like you do with i and element
        })(i, element), i * (1000 / 60), element);
    }
    ....
 }
```

Comment: On the same count alot of libraries out there (like jQuery) will fall apart horribly if you extend object.prototype, so if you use one of them hasOwnProperty is just a waste of cpu cycles.

Comment: @Martin Jespersen So you sell of the code with "WARNING DO ONLY USE WITH FRAMEWORKS A, B AND C" printed on them? Sorry, but using `hasOwnProperty` *is** a good practice.

Comment: nope i am just tired of a web filled with javascript code that is so far from being optimized that even chrome chokes on it, then again, i guess i should be thankful since i make my money cleaning up the mess others make :P

Comment: I really don't understand what you are getting at with the whole hasOwnProperty thing. I did not know I was setting a prototype?

Comment: @Martin Then go never use jQuery again, it's filled with calls to hasOwnProperty. What you are doing is premature optimization, nothing else.

Comment: @Wolfy I just wanted to point out a possible bug that might happen when other code (be it yours you write in 2 weeks) or another script that you might use on your page extends the prototype, since then strange things will end up in your `properties` object.

Comment: @Ivo Wetzel Oh right, I thought it was a problem with my current code. And I thought that my script was not working due to the length not existing and the for in statement not working because of it. So now I know there is nothing wrong with the object, do you know why it is only animating the height rather than both?

Comment: @Ivo easy... your example is fine and you are right it has both suspenders and belt, nothing wrong with it, i was just peddling a simpler and faster alternative - don't take it personal that we have differing opinions ;)

Comment: @Wofly You need to pass `p` into the animation wrapper too, just like `i` and `element` since the `for in loop` will otherwise override the `p`.

Comment: @Ivo Of course! Because I have functions within functions. Thank you for that!

Comment: Array-like objects also have length property:))) But they are not arrays.

Comment: @Alexandr Indeed, but it was trying to avoid even more confusion here, it should also be noted that the only real JS object that behaves "like" an array is arguments. The rest is part of the DOM :)

Comment: @Ivo Wetzel Of course your answer - is excelent! And it's absolutely enough to understand the reason of the problem.

Answer (score 46):

This is supported in node.js and newer environments.

```
var obj = {a: "a", b: "b"};
Object.keys(obj).length // 2
```

Comment: Not support in IE8, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 11):

If you are using [Underscore.js](https://underscorejs.org/#size), you can use `_.size()`:

```
_.size({one : 1, two : 2, three : 3});
=> 3
```

Comment: I'm yet to see the source but I hope that `size()` takes `hasOwnProperty` into account.

Answer (score 0):

Objects have no length, you'll need to use an array if you want that.

If you have to find the number of properties in an object there is only one way:

```
var length =0;
for(var i in obj) length++;
```

Comment: Use hasOwnProperty, please.

Comment: Why, how? Where does hasOwnProperty apply to this?

Comment: Better to just *not* update Object.prototype? Who does that? This is actually a great example!

Comment: @IvoWetzel an example would be appreciated.

I've used Martin Jespersen's answer here http://jsfiddle.net/jeykeu/qAH48/

Is it the way to go?

Answer (score 0):

Here's @Junaid Qadir Shekhanzai's general function for "finding the length of an object" (which as we're told, should properly be called "counting the properties of an object"). It combines solutions from @Ivo Wetzel and @Martin Jespersen:

```
function countProperties(myObj){
    var length = 0;
    if(typeof myObj != 'object'){
        return false;
    }
    for(var i in myObj) {
    length++;
    }
    return length;
}
```