# In javascript, when to use object literal and when to use array?

Tags: javascript, object-literal, javascript-objects

Here's a sample. My concern is both seem to do the job. which of them to prefer?

```
var fooArr = [{ "bar": {"blah": 9 } }];

for(var i in fooArr) {
    var value = fooArr[i].bar.blah;
console.log(value); //checking in firebug console
}

var fooObj = { "bar": {"blah": 9 } };
for(var i in fooObj) {
    var value = fooObj[i].blah;
console.log(value); //checking in firebug console
}
```

Also, the following seems to be not valid, Any way of avoiding array notation.

```
var fooObj1 = {
    { "bar": { "blah": 9 } },
    { "bar": { "blah": 4 } },
    { "bar": { "blah":12} }
};
```

So I had to modify the above code to something like below which works. Is it too too bad to be too much sticky with Object literals

```
var fooObj1 = {
    1:{ "bar": { "blah": 9 } },
    2:{ "bar": { "blah": 4 } },
    3:{ "bar": { "blah":12} }
};
```

Thanks again and in advance to those who help me with the query.

Comment: I've linked this to an existing question that partly answers my query. "...JavaScript object simply do not have a length property, only Arrays do. If you want to know the number of properties that are defined on a object, you have to iterate over them and count them..." http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690520/javascript-object-literal-length-undefined/4690581#4690581

Comment: Why are you avoiding array notation? It looks like you want a list of objects. An object is just a bunch of name/value pairs. In the 2nd example you have 3 sets of objects with no names to refer to them by.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The sample doesn't really compare objects and arrays. You're just adding a needless layer by putting an object in the first element of an array.

Use an object when you have to refer to something by name.

```
var obj = {}
```

//3 ways of doing the same thing:

```
var obj.newName = 'bob';

var obj['newName'] = 'bob';

var name = 'newName';
var obj[name] = 'bob';
```

The 2nd style isn't really necessary and might actually be a touch slower to access than the 1st but it helps you understand how the 3rd can be useful. Or you could have done the following outright:

```
var obj = { newName:'bob' }
```

If you want a bunch of names in an object, it would get a bit silly:

```
var obj = { newName:'bob', anotherNewName:'sue', yetAnotherNewName:'billy' }

obj.newName === 'bob'
obj.anotherNewName === 'sue'
//etc...
```

That's what arrays are for.

```
var listOfNewNames = ['bob','sue','billy']
listOfNewNames[0] === 'bob'
listOfNewNames[1] === 'sue'
//etc...
```

Of course, nothing prevents you from assigning an array to an object property:

```
obj { listOfNewNames:['bob','sue','billy'] }

obj.listOfNewNames[0] === 'bob'
```

Or, as demonstrated above, multiple objects in an array:

```
var listOfMonsters = [
    { monsterName:'Grarrr',eats:'people' },
    { monsterName:'Wadsworth',eats:'other monsters'}
];

listOfMonsters[1].monsterName === 'Wadsworth'
```

Objects are typically more about keeping groups of related values and methods together for ease of reference. Arrays are just a list of stuff that all can typically be assumed to apply to or derive from the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

A `for .. in` loop iterates over enumerables. You might want to [read up](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/01/04/exploring-javascript-for-in-loops/) on it.

If you have an array of objects I would suggest a traditional `for` loop:

```
var fooObjs = [ {bar: "blah"}, {bar: "blah2"} ];
for (var i = 0, j = fooObj.length; i < j; i++) {
  console.log(fooObjs[i].bar);
}
```

If you have an object with multiple properties, then you could use the `for .. in` loop:

```
var fooObj = { bar: "blah", baz: "blah2" };
for (var i in fooObj) {
  if (fooObj.hasOwnProperty(i)) { // So you don't log prototype properties
    console.log(fooObj[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an array when you know you'll have more than one objects. A one item array isn't needed when only one object will be used.

As you can see, the syntax is also a bit more complex (you have `[...]` and `bar` when using arrays -> more characters are used), so don't use it if you don't need to.

Answer (score 1):

Use array if you need lists and use objects if you need properties.

In the above case, I would prefer the latter one.

Aside from that, never use `for in` on an array (it is [extremely slow](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#arrays) and defeats the purpose) and always use [`hasOwnProperty`](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#hasownproperty) when iterating over an object's properties.

Comment: aha, performance aspect of "for in" was great to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You use an array when you need to use more than one item. Example:

```
var fooArr = [{ bar: { blah: 9 } },{ bar: { blah: 4 } },{ bar: { blah: 12 } }];
for(var i in fooArr) {
  var value = fooArr[i].bar.blah;
  console.log(value); // will log "9", "4" and "12"
}
```

In the second example you only have a single object, so you don't need the the loop at all to access the property:

```
var fooObj = { bar: { blah: 9 } };
var value = fooObj.bar.blah;
console.log(value);
```