# data.length is undefined following a successful getJSON operation

Tags: jquery, json, each

I'm populating a drop down with JSON data from getJSON.

Populating is working fine, but trying to establish that it's finished by comparing to `data.length` is not working as `data.length` is `undefined` and I can't see why!

The data looks like:

```
{
    "1": {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Plymouth"
    },
    "2": {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Torquay"
    }
}
```

My code looks like:

```
$('.locationList').empty();
$('.locationList').append('<option value="">Select...</option>');
$.getJSON('/Settings/locations.txt', function (data) {
    var dataNum = data.length;
    var counter = 1;
    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
        $('.locationList').append('<option value="' + data[i].id + '">' + data[i].name + '</option>');
        if (counter >= dataNum) {
            $('#bookTo').val(locationID + 1);
            $('#transferFrom').val(locationID);
        };
        counter++;
    });
});
```

This section:

```
if (counter >= dataNum) {
    $('#bookTo').val(locationID + 1);
    $('#transferFrom').val(locationID);
};
counter++;
```

Is meant to allow me to preset the values of the drop down boxes once the `$.each` loop has completed (this works with other lists), but it's not happening.

When I run `alert(data.length)` I get `undefined` which makes no sense as `data` clearly does have a `length` in order for it to populate the drop down box properly through the `$.each`, which it does!

EDIT: sorry, should add, the variable `locationID` is declared earlier in the script from a Cookie and IS valid

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript object literal length === undefined?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690520/javascript-object-literal-length-undefined) `data` is an object, not a string or an array. Objects do not expose a `length` property.

Comment: Why exactly do you need the `dataNum` variable when you have the index value of jQuery's .each() function ?

Comment: I need the dataNum variable to determine when `$.each` has finished, because despite what it says in the docs, otherwise the value selection of the drop down box happens before it's fully populated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an object:

```
data = {
    "1": {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Plymouth"
    },
    "2": {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Torquay"
    }
}
```

and it doesn't have a `length` property.

see: only the property `1` and `2`.

Are you sure you want it as an object rater then an array:

```
data = [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Plymouth"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Torquay"
    }
]
```

then you have the `length` property and a lot of other native array methods like `sort`. And you can access your data like this:

```
data[0]
```

witch is equal to:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Plymouth"
}
```

Comment: :D I've changed the source of `locations.txt` and now it works, thanks!
`[{"id":"1","label":"1","name":"Plymouth"},{"id":"2","label":"2","name":"Torquay"}]`

Answer (score 3):

Probably not the best way of doing this, but something like this could probably be a quick fix?

```
$('.locationList').empty();
$('.locationList').append('<option value="">Select...</option>');
$.getJSON('/Settings/locations.txt', function (data) {
    var dataNum = 0;
    for (i in data) {if (data.hasOwnProperty(i)) {dataNum++;}}    
    var counter = 1;
    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
        $('.locationList').append('<option value="' + data[i].id + '">' + data[i].name + '</option>');
        if (counter >= dataNum) {
            $('#bookTo').val(locationID + 1);
            $('#transferFrom').val(locationID);
        };
        counter++;
    });
});
```

Comment: Yeh, I did think that. In this case it'd be fine as it's a very simple list, but it's not good practice.

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON:

```
{"1":{"id":"1","name":"Plymouth"},"2":{"id":"2","name":"Torquay"}}
```

is an object, not an array so the `length` property is not defined.
If you want to parse it as an array your server needs to give a response like:

```
{"response": [{"1":{"id":"1","name":"Plymouth"}},
{"2":{"id":"2","name":"Torquay"}}] }
```

with `[]` instead of `{}`

Comment: not right! An array doesn't take the string like json: `{string: value, string: value}`. Arrays is: `[value, value]`

Comment: That can't be correct or the rest of the function would fail, surely? Ah... reading @AndreasAl answer is pointing me in the right direction along with this comment... sort of!

Answer (score 0):

When response.data == [],
this works:

```
if (response.data.length === 0)
```

This is a Array then has length prospriety.