# using .length on vars that don't have the length property results in crash

Tags: javascript, crash, variable-length

I have a big array which contains all kind of types (booleans, arrays, null, ...), and I am trying to access their propiety `arr[i].length`, but some of them obiously fail to have length.

I wouldn't mind if the guys missing length returned `undefined` (I could simply use `arr[i].length||0` or something like that), but this is not the case, the whole thing crashes with some values (`null` or `undefined` for example).

```
var i, len, arr;

arr = [true, ["elm_0"], 99, "abc"]; //crashes if you add 'null' or 'undefined'

for(i = 0, len = arr.length ; i<len ; i++){
    document.write(arr[i].length + "<br>");
}

document.write("I was executed");
```

- What other vars will crash besides `null` and `undefined`?
- How to prevent this from happening?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690520/javascript-object-literal-length-undefined   - this answers your exact question

Comment: Yes, that is because `undefined` does not have any properties.

Comment: @PaulS.: The OP is suggesting that adding the values `null` or `undefined` to `arr` will result in a crash when taking `arr[i].length`; If I'm not mistaken, `if(arr)` will still return true in this scenario, and the loop still executed.

Comment: @usernametbd I was typing in the wrong place

Comment: @ScottSelby I belive it doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for `arr[i]` before `arr[i].length`

```
var i, len, arr;

arr = [true, ["elm_0"], 99, "abc"];

if(arr) for(i = 0, len = arr.length || 0 ; i<len ; i++){
    if(arr[i]) document.write((arr[i].length || 0) + "<br>");
    else document.write(0 + "<br>"); // what to do if no arr[i]
}

document.write("I was executed");
```

You can use a ternary operator, too `(arr[i]?arr[i].length||0:0)`

Comment: I am sure my arr will always be an arr, the first `len=...||0` is not really necessary, but I am definetely using the `arr[i]?arr[i].length||0:0` line

Comment: Note: This will skip some values that actually have a length property, like `""`.

Answer (score 2):

You're going to get a `TypeError` stating `undefined` has no properties. Nothing you can do here but wrap it in a try catch for `TypeError`s.

Note that this is the same reason referencing a property on something that evaluates to undefined will return a `ReferenceError`: `undefined` should never have properties.

Comment: there seem to be other ways to prevent this without catching anything, your 'nothing you can do... except catch' will start to look incorrect-er every time someone post a working answer D:

Comment: @ajax333221 You're taking that a bit too literally. What I mean is that there is no way to prevent an error from popping up when you try to evaluate a property on `undefined` or `null`. The other answers are just ways of avoiding that evaluation (checking for null undefined and skipping the iteration etc.).

Comment: you are right, but well you can't denny at first glance it looks like you are saying there is not other possible work around except catching, my confusion is understandable

Comment: @ajax333221 I apologise sincerely.

Answer (score 2):

You can just check for null without doing a type specific check, that will catch undefined values also.

```
var i, len, arr;
arr = [true, ["elm_0"], 99, "abc", null, undefined];
for (i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (arr[i] != null) {
        console.log(arr[i].length);
    }
}
console.log("I was executed");
```

Comment: @Asad: Yes, I already found that out, and adjusted the answer. :)

Comment: something like that will work, since you are using a weak check I think there wont be much difference if I use `if(arr[i])` or something like that, which is basically what _Paul S._ did so I gave him a +1 too

Comment: @ajax333221: Yes, you will get the same result for most values, but for example the value `""` will be evaluated to false eventhough it is an object, and actually has a `length` property.

Comment: those will go to the `else` and I think giving falsey values 0 len is safe, I wrote `(arr[i])?arr[i].length||0:0` which is exactly what Paul said, I am starting to like his answer more, and you have plenty rep, and I should not feel sorry, changing accepted answer is not wrong please respect my opinion I have this power and help please dont be mad, trust me I feel worse than you

Comment: @ajax333221: NP. That solution works too, as long as you are aware of the difference, and it doesn't cause a problem in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var i, len, arr;

arr = [true, ["elm_0"], 99, "abc"]; //crashes if you add 'null' or 'undefined'

for(i = 0, len = arr.length ; i<len ; i++){

try{
console.log(arr[i].length);
}Catch(e){console.log(0);}
}

console.log("I was executed");
```

Answer (score -1):

If your only goal is to determine if one of these objects is an array, then instead of:

```
for(i = 0, len = arr.length ; i<len ; i++){
    console.log(arr[i].length);
}
```

You should try this:

```
for(i = 0, len = arr.length ; i<len ; i++){
    if (arr[i] instanceof Array)
        console.log(arr[i].length);
}
```