# Get total number of items on Json object?

Tags: javascript, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Length of Javascript Object (ie. Associative Array)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223/length-of-javascript-object-ie-associative-array)

I have an object similar to this one:

```
var jsonArray = {
  '-1': {
    '-1': 'b',
    '2': 'a',
    '10': 'c'
  },
  '2': {
    '-1': 'a',
    '2': 'b',
    '10': 'a'
  },
  '5': {
    '-1': 'a',
    '2': 'a',
    '10': 'b'
  }
};
```

I'm trying to get it's length, the problem is that `jsonArray.length` returns 5 instead of 3 (which is the total items it has). The array is relatively long (has 1000x2000 items) and this must be done a lot of times every second. How can I get the number of items more efficiently?

Comment: `jsonArray` isn't an array.

Comment: `Object.keys(jsonArray).length;` an object does'nt have a length property, and your object is neither an array nor valid json.

Answer (score 182, accepted):

In addition to kieran's answer, apparently, modern browsers have an `Object.keys` function. In this case, you could do this:

```
Object.keys(jsonArray).length;
```

More details in this answer on [How to list the properties of a javascript object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/208020/165988)

Comment: why do you write Object.keys(...) and not just keys(), It works both ways, what is the difference between those two ???

Comment: Chrome v54 doe not have this.

Answer (score 22):

That's an Object and you want to count the properties of it.

```
Object.keys(jsonArray).length
```

References:

- [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).
- [Kangax's compat table](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/).

Answer (score 6):

Is that your actual code? A javascript object (which is what you've given us) does not have a length property, so in this case `exampleArray.length` returns undefined rather than 5.

[This stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690520/javascript-object-literal-length-undefined) explains the length differences between an object and an array, and [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223/length-of-javascript-object-ie-associative-array) shows how to get the 'size' of an object.