# Count the values in json using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I'm new to javascript and i want to count the values of this json string:

```
{
    "files": [
        {
            "name": "doc1.pdf",
            "title": "networking",
            "path": "mfpreader.comze.com\/files\/doc1.pdf"
        },
        {
            "name": "doc2.pdf",
            "title": "Armoogum",
            "path": "mfpreader.comze.com\/files\/doc2.pdf"
        }
    ]
}
```

the json is saved in the **res.responseJSON.data**.

here is the code i tried:

```
$("#demo").html(JSON.stringify(res.responseJSON.data));

var jsonObject = JSON.parse(res.responseJSON.data);
var propertyNames = Object.keys(jsonObject);

alert("There are "+propertyNames.length+" properties in the object");
```

The value is get is 1. It should be 2 since we have 2 documents.

can i have some please. Thanks

Comment: `propertyNames.name.length` - count the `name` field not `files` field as you are

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get total number of items on Json object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13782698/get-total-number-of-items-on-json-object)

Comment: get the array from the files and then check the array's length

Comment: Already have answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6756104/get-size-of-json-object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the required output what you want you have to do like below

```
var v={"files":[{"name":"doc1.pdf","title":"networking","path":"mfpreader.comze.com\/files\/doc1.pdf"},{"name":"doc2.pdf","title":"Armoogum","path":"mfpreader.comze.com\/files\/doc2.pdf"}]};

console.log(v.files.length)
```

Comment: Thank you all guys

Answer (score 1):

> Assign `json` response to a variable i.e.

```
var result = {"files":[{"name":"doc1.pdf","title":"networking","path":"mfpreader.comze.com/files/doc1.pdf"},{"name":"doc2.pdf","title":"Armoogum","path":"mfpreader.comze.com/files/doc2.pdf"}]}
```

**Now Count Files**

`result.files.length`

*output* : 2

Answer (score 0):

Your json object has only 1 key at root level. i.e. "files"

```
jsonObject = {"files":[{"name":"doc1.pdf","title":"networking","path":"mfpreader.comze.com\/files\/doc1.pdf"},{"name":"doc2.pdf","title":"Armoogum","path":"mfpreader.comze.com\/files\/doc2.pdf"}]}
Object.keys(jsonObject)
   // will return ->  ["files"]
```

Answer (score 0):

DhruvPathak is correct - your solution is returning 1 since there is only 1 key at the root layer of the JSON object.

If you want to count the number of keys in the lower layers, you could do something like:

```
 $("#demo").html(JSON.stringify(res.responseJSON.data));  

       var jsonObject = JSON.parse(res.responseJSON.data);

       var numProperties = 0;

       for (item in jsonObject) {
           numProperties += Object.keys(item).length;
       }
         alert("There are " + numProperties + " properties in the object");
```

You can find the number of properties in any layer of the JSON object by using nested `for` loops.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `res.responseJSON.data.files.length`

```
$("#demo").html(JSON.stringify(res.responseJSON.data));

//var jsonObject = JSON.parse(res.responseJSON.data);
//var propertyNames = Object.keys(jsonObject);

alert("There are "+res.responseJSON.data.files.length+" properties in the object");
```