# How to get number of arrays in a JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

Below is my JSON. I want to get number and name of array(s) in this object. This is dynamically created so I don't know about its number and name(s). Here are 2 Arrays in this example, named Table and Table1.

```
"{
      "Table": [
        {
          "Day": "Jan",
          "Counts": 20,
          "SrNo": 1,
          "Title": "test2",
          "ProfilePic": "/Image1.jpg" 
        },
        {
          "Day": "Feb",
          "Counts": 10,
          "SrNo": 2,        
          "Title": "test2",
          "ProfilePic": "/Image1.jpg"          
        }
    ],
 "Table1": [
    {
      "Day": "01",
      "Counts": 5,
      "SrNo": 1,       
      "Title": "test3",
      "ProfilePic": "/Image2.jpg"
     },
     {
      "Day": "02",
      "Counts": 9,
      "SrNo": 2,        
      "Title": "test3",
      "ProfilePic": "/Image2.jpg",        
     }
   ]
 }"
```

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the arrays will only be on the first "level", and not in nested objects?

Comment: thanks for the answers, i my case i need to json.stringify i.e, Object.keys(JSON.parse(obj)).length;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get total number of items on Json object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13782698/get-total-number-of-items-on-json-object)

Comment: its always on the first level @Phillip..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Try below mentioned code,**

```
Object.keys(jsonObject).length;
```

Also refer... : [Get total number of items on Json object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13782698/get-total-number-of-items-on-json-object)

**To get all the names :**

```
var keys = Object.keys(jsonObject); // this will return root level title ["Table" , "Table1"]
```

Comment: can we get names as well?

Comment: To get names, just remove the `.length` part. You will now have an array of the keys :)

Comment: @SunilChaudhary ,  var keys = Object.keys(jsonObject);  // to get titles

Comment: Note that this will only work if the object contains only arrays.

Comment: if there is no array, will it return 0?

Comment: @SunilChaudhary , no this is for json object , so don't worry

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that every property in the object contains an array, you can just count the number of properties using `Object.keys`, like this:

```
var arrayCount = Object.keys(obj).length;
```

Alternatively, if you actually want to determine the type of the property, in case there some other types in the object, you would need to loop through and check each property individually, which could be done using `filter()` like this:

```js
var obj = {
  "Table": [{
      "Day": "Jan",
      "Counts": 20,
      "SrNo": 1,
      "Title": "test2",
      "ProfilePic": "/Image1.jpg"
    },
    {
      "Day": "Feb",
      "Counts": 10,
      "SrNo": 2,
      "Title": "test2",
      "ProfilePic": "/Image1.jpg"
    }
  ],
  "Table1": [{
      "Day": "01",
      "Counts": 5,
      "SrNo": 1,
      "Title": "test3",
      "ProfilePic": "/Image2.jpg"
    },
    {
      "Day": "02",
      "Counts": 9,
      "SrNo": 2,
      "Title": "test3",
      "ProfilePic": "/Image2.jpg",
    }
  ],
  'NotArray1': 'foo', // < not an array
  'isArray': false // < not an array
}

var arrayCount = Object.keys(obj).filter(function(key) {
  return obj[key].constructor === Array;
}).length;
console.log(arrayCount);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) in order to return the total of all the object property values that are valid array:

```js
var obj = {
    "Table": [{
      "Day": "Jan",
      "Counts": 20,
      "SrNo": 1,
      "Title": "test2",
      "ProfilePic": "/Image1.jpg"
    }, {
      "Day": "Feb",
      "Counts": 10,
      "SrNo": 2,
      "Title": "test2",
      "ProfilePic": "/Image1.jpg"
    }],
    "Table1": [{
        "Day": "01",
        "Counts": 5,
        "SrNo": 1,
        "Title": "test3",
        "ProfilePic": "/Image2.jpg"
      }, {
        "Day": "02",
        "Counts": 9,
        "SrNo": 2,
        "Title": "test3",
        "ProfilePic": "/Image2.jpg"
      }
    ],
    "Table2": false
  },
  arrayCount = Object.keys(obj).reduce(function (acc, val) {
    return Array.isArray(obj[val]) ? ++acc : acc;
  }, 0);

console.log(arrayCount);
```

Answer (score 0):

In a modern browser, to count arrays in a object

```
Object.keys(obj).filter((e) => Array.isArray(obj[e])).length
```