# Get total number of objects in JSON but Javascript Object.keys().length returns undefined

Tags: javascript, json

I am attempting to get values from a returned JSON object form a REST service.  When I attempt to get the number of "rows" or "records" -- not the number of keys -- I continually get `undefined` when using `Object.keys(json).length`.

I have reviewed and tried a few of these answers on these posts:

[Length of a JavaScript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223/length-of-a-javascript-object)

[Get total number of items on Json object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13782698/get-total-number-of-items-on-json-object)

Here is the code I am using:

```
        $.getJSON(finalURL, function(json) {
            console.log("json: " + json);
            console.log("json.length: " + json.length);
            var propertyNames = Object.keys(json).length;
            console.log("propertyNames.length: " + propertyNames.length);
            var jsonLength = propertyNames.length;
            console.log("jsonLength: " + jsonLength);
            if (isNaN(jsonLength)) {
                console.log(jsonLength + " is not a number");
            } else {
                console.log(jsonLength + " is a number");
            }
            if (jsonLength > 0) {
                console.log("jsonLength > 0");
            } else {
                console.log("jsonLength = 0");
            }
        });
```

Here is the returned JSON:

```
{"id":1,"providerName":"Acme","providerID":"12343","providerLegacyID":"832940","contactName":"John Doe","contactEmail":"jdoe@this.eml","contactPhone":"3035551212","address1":"5999 Second Street","address2":"","city":"Denver","state":"CO","zip":"80203","providerKey":"0be32d8057924e718a8b6b4186254756","userKeys":null,"approved":null,"active":null,"createdBy":"Dan Zeller","createdByKey":"c6f4cf6a47a44092a3655420bd4a3f26","createdByRole":"ADMIN","createdDate":1517927130501,"updatedBy":null,"updatedByKey":null,"updatedByRole":null,"updatedDate":null,"removedBy":null,"removedByKey":null,"removedByRole":null,"removedByDate":null,"restoredBy":null,"restoredByKey":null,"restoredByRole":null,"restoredByDate":null}
```

So I am expecting the length of the JSON object to be 1 with the above JSON.  If more are returned, that number would go up.

Here is the output from the code:

```
json: [object Object]
json.length: undefined
propertyNames.length: undefined
jsonLength: undefined
undefined is not a number
jsonLength = 0
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: `console.log("json: ", json);` should give you better idea what that object is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.keys(json)` returns an array, so its `.length` is a number.

You're trying to get the `.length` of a number, which makes no sense.

Comment: Is there another way to correct this?  Is there a sample I could use? So, using `var propertyNames = Object.keys(json).length;` will not work?  Thanks

Comment: @Dan: Why do you think that won't work?  Your problem is that `.length.length` makes no sense.

Comment: `var propertyNames = Object.keys(json).length;` returns `32` but what I am looking for is to return `1` since I see only one "record" returned.  If 2 were returned, I am looking for `2` to be returned.  I appreciate the help!

Comment: @Dan: That's not how JSON works.  It sounds like you're describing an array, but you don't actually have an array.

Answer (score 0):

you can use somethink like this :

```
  var myObject = {"id":1,"providerName":"Acme","providerID":"12343","providerLegacyID":"832940","contactName":"John Doe","contactEmail":"jdoe@this.eml","contactPhone":"3035551212","address1":"5999 Second Street","address2":"","city":"Denver","state":"CO","zip":"80203","providerKey":"0be32d8057924e718a8b6b4186254756","userKeys":null,"approved":null,"active":null,"createdBy":"Dan Zeller","createdByKey":"c6f4cf6a47a44092a3655420bd4a3f26","createdByRole":"ADMIN","createdDate":1517927130501,"updatedBy":null,"updatedByKey":null,"updatedByRole":null,"updatedDate":null,"removedBy":null,"removedByKey":null,"removedByRole":null,"removedByDate":null,"restoredBy":null,"restoredByKey":null,"restoredByRole":null,"restoredByDate":null};

  var count = Object.keys(myObject).length;
  console.log(count);
```

Comment: So, the `json` object I am returning will have to be set to `myobject` to work?  Something like `var myObject = json;`? Thanks

Comment: No.. myObject is just an example to define your json , cause i tested on plnkr and i miss your part of code wich return json

Comment: you can do this : var count = Object.keys(json).length;

Comment: I tried defining the `myObject` in my code and still got `undefined` when trying to get the length.  Would is be something in the JSON formatting?  The code to return the JSON is in a Play Framework controller: `public Result restGetProvider(String providerKey) {
  Provider provider = Provider.findByProviderKey(providerKey);
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  JsonNode jsonData = mapper.convertValue(provider, JsonNode.class);
  System.out.println("jsonData: " + jsonData);
  return ok(jsonData);
 }`