# How to get all the 'items' of an API array from GitHub?

Tags: javascript, async-await, github-api

I am trying to get a list of repositories, that is my code does a search for repositories with a filter

The Javascript gets a result, with multiple items that contain the data for each repository that fit the filter using the URL: `https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=piccolowen+in:name`.

I can do `console.log(result.items[0].name)` to get the first repository's `name` value, but I want get all of the repositories from the search printed to the console. I also want the code to be able to print all of the repositories and their values no matter how many repos fit the filter.

Here is the current code I want to add on to:

```
window.onload = func()
    async function func() {
        const url = 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=piccolowen+in:name'
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const result = await response.json();
        const apiresult = document.getElementById('thisisanid') 
        console.log(result)
}
```

Any ideas on how I could do this?

EDIT:
I found the answer to my problem using a while loop from this question: [Get total number of items on Json object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13782698/get-total-number-of-items-on-json-object)

```
const resultLength = Object.keys(result.items).length
var arrnum = 0
while (arrnum < resultLength) {
//execute code
}
```

EDIT 2:
The code in my previous edit will crash a page. Still working on a solution for this huge bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `results.items` returns an array of objects, you can use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to return all the item names, i.e.:

```
result.items.map(item => item.name)
```

If you want to simply filter out some properties, you can also do [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring). Let's say you want an array of items that only contain their `name`, `id`, and `description`, then you can do this:

```
result.items.map(({ name, id, description }) => ({ name, id, description }))
```

```js
async function func() {
  const url = 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=piccolowen+in:name'
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const result = await response.json();

  // Returns an array of item names
  console.log(result.items.map(item => item.name));

  // Returns an array of object with selected keys
  console.log(result.items.map(({ name, id, description }) => ({ name, id, description })));
}

func();
```

Answer (score 0):

The array has `map function`, which accepts a callback function. It iterate through all the elements and call the callback function and push data to the newly created array.

> The map() method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

**More:**
[Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
const array1 = [1, 4, 9, 16];

// pass a function to map
const map1 = array1.map(x => x * 2);

console.log(map1);
// expected output: Array [2, 8, 18, 32]
```

```js
window.load = main();
const nameMapper = (item) => item.name;
const liMapper = (item) => `<li>${item.name}</li>`;
async function main() {
  const url = "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=piccolowen+in:name";
  const result = await fetch(url).then((x) => x.json());
  const names = result.items.map(nameMapper);
  const apiresult = document.getElementById("thisisanid");
  apiresult.textContent = names;

  const ul = document.getElementById("list");
  ul.innerHTML = result.items.map(liMapper).join("");
}
```

```css
#list li{
  list-style: none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  max-width: 400px;
}
```

```html
    <div id="thisisanid"></div>
    <ul id="list">
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like!

```
let list = document.getElementById('list');
let htmlTemplate = result.items.map(function(item) {
   return item.name
}).join("")

list.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', htmlTemplate)
```

or you can use template literal
foe example
when you returning value in items.map()

```
return `${item.id}: ${item.name}`
```